# Call Java method using Map values

Tags: java, dictionary, call

I have several classes that require wrapper methods that look similar to this:

```
class MyClass {
  public MyClass(String arg1, Date arg2, Integer arg3) {
    // Do something with supplied arguments
  }
}

class MyClassWrapper {
  private ArrayList<MyClass> objects = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
  private final String[] names = {"firstparam","secondparam","thirdparam"};
  private final Object[] classes = {String.class,Date.class,Integer.class};

  public void addEntry(Map<String, Object> params) {
    objects.add(new MyClass(
                (String)params.get(names[0]),
                (Date)params.get(names[1]),
                (Integer)params.get(names[2])
                ));
  }

  public ArrayList<MyClass> getEntries() {
    return objects;
  }

  public Object[] getColumnClasses() {
    return classes;
  }

  public String[] getColumnLabels() {
    return names;
  }
}
```

These are used in code that reads data from external sources into a `HashMap` and then calls `addEntry` to call the `MyClass` constructor. I write my own `***Wrapper` classes so that I do not need to add an extra `MyClass` constructor to read the `Map` directly.

All my `***Wrapper` classes look the same except for having different `names` and `classes` members, and a hand-written `addEntry`. Is there a way to avoid manually writing `addEntry` to make use of `names` and `classes` to automatically pass the map values into the `MyClass` constructor?

Comment: Yes, you could probably cobble something together with reflection.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It feels like something that could be done at compile time (using generics?). If this were C++ I'd expect some clever metaprogramming solution...

Comment: Note that it only becomes easy to access parameter names with Java 8 (to look them up in the map). With earlier versions of Java you probably want a library to help you, Spring and others have support for that (by reading and parsing the .class file)

Comment: @beldaz Java is most emphatically not C++, and Java generics are really a compile time type checking system.

Comment: You could use reflection with configuration files .. e.g. an external json file that maps different types of MyClass and its fields

Comment: @saugata That sounds promising. Any chance you could post an Answer showing what you have in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution for you:

**Step 1:**

Following is `MyClass.java` exactly as specified in the question.

```
public class MyClass {

private String arg1;
private Date arg2;
private Integer arg3;

public MyClass(String arg1, Date arg2, Integer arg3) {
        this.arg1 = arg1;
        this.arg2 = arg2;
        this.arg3 = arg3;
    }

@Override
public String toString() {
        return "MyClass [arg1=" + arg1 + ", arg2=" + arg2 + ", arg3=" + arg3 + "]";
    }

}
```

**Step 2:**

Now create the wrapper class `MyClassWrapper.java` as follows:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MyClassWrapper<T> {
    private List<T> objects = new ArrayList<T>();
    private String[] names;
    private Class<?>[] classes;
    private Class<T> clazz;

    public MyClassWrapper(Class<T> clazz, String[] names, Class<?>[] classes) throws Exception {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.names = names;
        this.classes = classes;
    }

    public void addEntry(Map<String, Object> params) throws Exception {
        Constructor<T> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(classes);
        Object[] parameters = new Object[names.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            parameters[i] = params.get(names[i]);
        }
        objects.add(constructor.newInstance(parameters));
    }

    public List<T> getEntries() {
        return objects;
    }

    public Class<?>[] getColumnClasses() {
        return classes;
    }

    public String[] getColumnLabels() {
        return names;
    }
}
```

**Step 3:**

Now following class `MyClassWrapperDemo` is going to test `MyClassWrapper` with parameter `MyClass`. But you may use `MyClassWrapper` with other classes which look similar to `MyClass`. You do not need to define another version of wrapper class.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MyClassWrapperDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MyClassWrapper<MyClass> wrapper=
                new MyClassWrapper<MyClass>(
                MyClass.class, 
                new String[]{"firstparam", "secondparam", "thirdparam" },
                new Class<?>[]{String.class, Date.class, Integer.class}
                );     
        Map<String, Object> params =new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("firstparam", "HelloWorld");
        params.put("secondparam", new Date());
        params.put("thirdparam", 30);
        wrapper.addEntry(params);
        List<MyClass> list= wrapper.getEntries();
        String[] lebels = wrapper.getColumnLabels();
        Class<?>[]  objects= wrapper.getColumnClasses();
        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lebels));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(objects));

    }

}
```

Comment: This is also a good solution. Again, looks like someone's downvoted it without explaining why, which seems like bad manners to me. +1 from me though.

Comment: Hi @beldaz could you please have a look at my answer once again? Now class `MyClassWrapper` is truly parameter based as it can be assigned different names and classes members.

Comment: Thanks, yes, looks like just what I need. Not much in it between yours and Matt's but I'll accept yours since it was posted earlier. It would have been useful to know why someone felt the need to down-vote it, but from my view it looks great.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you want a Factory pattern. Using reflection you can do it. Just need an Interface and implementation classes with those own behaviors each. This class you build could be the factory.

Comment: This sounds like a possibility but I was hoping for something a bit more concrete. Could you expand to include some sample code?